# Time series forecasting by lm() using lapply

Tags: r, time-series, linear-regression, lapply, lm

I was trying to forecast a time series problem using `lm()` and my data looks like below

```
Customer_key  date         sales
 A35          2018-05-13   31
 A35          2018-05-20   20
 A35          2018-05-27   43
 A35          2018-06-03   31
 BH22         2018-05-13   60
 BH22         2018-05-20   67
 BH22         2018-05-27   78
 BH22         2018-06-03   55
```

Converted my `df` to a list format by

```
df <- dcast(df, date ~ customer_key,value.var = c("sales"))
df <- subset(df, select = -c(dt))
demandWithKey <- as.list(df)
```

Trying to write a function such that applying this function across all customers

```
my_fun <- function(x) {
  fit <- lm(ds_load ~ date, data=df) ## After changing to list ds_load and date column names
                                     ## are no longer available for formula
  fit_b <- forecast(fit$fitted.values, h=20) ## forecast using lm()
  return(data.frame(c(fit$fitted.values, fit_b[["mean"]])))
}

fcast <- lapply(df, my_fun)
```

I know the above function doesn't work, but basically I'm looking for getting both the fitted values and forecasted values for a grouped data.
But I've tried all other methods using `tslm()` (converting into time series data) and so on but no luck I can get the `lm()` work somehow on just one customer though. Also many questions/posts were on just fitting the model but I would like to forecast too at same time.

Answer (score 0):

lm() is for a regression model
but here you have a time serie so for forecasting the serie you have to use one of the time serie model (ARMA ARCH GARCH...)
so you can use the function in r : auto.arima() in "forecast" package

Comment: Thanks for replying.I do have a arima model for other customers, but I can do lm() individually for each customers. I'm looking for a grouped data at same time applying lm().

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're up to exactly, but you could make this less complicated.

Using `by` avoids the need to reshape your data, it splits your data e.g. by customer ID as in your case and applies a function on the subsets (i.e. it's a combination of `split` and `lapply`; see `?by`).

Since you want to compare fitted and forecasted values somehow in your result, you probably need `predict` rather than `$fitted.values`, otherwise the values won't be of same length. Because your independent variable is a date in weekly intervals, you may use `seq.Date` and take the first date as a starting value; the sequence has length actual values (`nrow` each customer) plus `h=` argument of the `forecast`.

For demonstration purposes I add the fitted values as first column in the following.

```
res <- by(dat, dat$cus_key, function(x) {
      H <- 20  ## globally define 'h'
      fit <- lm(sales ~ date, x)
      fitted <- fit$fitted.values
      pred <- predict(fit, newdata=data.frame(
        date=seq(x$date[1], length.out= nrow(x) + H, by="week")))
      fcst <- c(fitted, forecast(fitted, h=H)$mean)
      fit.na <- `length<-`(unname(fitted), length(pred))  ## for demonstration
      return(cbind(fit.na, pred, fcst))
      })
```

### Result

```
res
# dat$cus_key: A28
#    fit.na  pred  fcst
# 1    41.4  41.4  41.4
# 2    47.4  47.4  47.4
# 3    53.4  53.4  53.4
# 4    59.4  59.4  59.4
# 5    65.4  65.4  65.4
# 6      NA  71.4  71.4
# 7      NA  77.4  77.4
# 8      NA  83.4  83.4
# 9      NA  89.4  89.4
# 10     NA  95.4  95.4
# 11     NA 101.4 101.4
# 12     NA 107.4 107.4
# 13     NA 113.4 113.4
# 14     NA 119.4 119.4
# 15     NA 125.4 125.4
# 16     NA 131.4 131.4
# 17     NA 137.4 137.4
# 18     NA 143.4 143.4
# 19     NA 149.4 149.4
# 20     NA 155.4 155.4
# 21     NA 161.4 161.4
# 22     NA 167.4 167.4
# 23     NA 173.4 173.4
# 24     NA 179.4 179.4
# 25     NA 185.4 185.4
# ---------------------------------------------------------------- 
# dat$cus_key: B16
#    fit.na pred fcst
# 1    49.0 49.0 49.0
# 2    47.7 47.7 47.7
# 3    46.4 46.4 46.4
# 4    45.1 45.1 45.1
# 5    43.8 43.8 43.8
# 6      NA 42.5 42.5
# 7      NA 41.2 41.2
# 8      NA 39.9 39.9
# 9      NA 38.6 38.6
# 10     NA 37.3 37.3
# 11     NA 36.0 36.0
# 12     NA 34.7 34.7
# 13     NA 33.4 33.4
# 14     NA 32.1 32.1
# 15     NA 30.8 30.8
# 16     NA 29.5 29.5
# 17     NA 28.2 28.2
# 18     NA 26.9 26.9
# 19     NA 25.6 25.6
# 20     NA 24.3 24.3
# 21     NA 23.0 23.0
# 22     NA 21.7 21.7
# 23     NA 20.4 20.4
# 24     NA 19.1 19.1
# 25     NA 17.8 17.8
# ---------------------------------------------------------------- 
# dat$cus_key: C12
#    fit.na  pred  fcst
# 1    56.4  56.4  56.4
# 2    53.2  53.2  53.2
# 3    50.0  50.0  50.0
# 4    46.8  46.8  46.8
# 5    43.6  43.6  43.6
# 6      NA  40.4  40.4
# 7      NA  37.2  37.2
# 8      NA  34.0  34.0
# 9      NA  30.8  30.8
# 10     NA  27.6  27.6
# 11     NA  24.4  24.4
# 12     NA  21.2  21.2
# 13     NA  18.0  18.0
# 14     NA  14.8  14.8
# 15     NA  11.6  11.6
# 16     NA   8.4   8.4
# 17     NA   5.2   5.2
# 18     NA   2.0   2.0
# 19     NA  -1.2  -1.2
# 20     NA  -4.4  -4.4
# 21     NA  -7.6  -7.6
# 22     NA -10.8 -10.8
# 23     NA -14.0 -14.0
# 24     NA -17.2 -17.2
# 25     NA -20.4 -20.4
```

As you can see, prediction and forecast yield the same values, since both methods are based on the same single explanatory variable `date` in this case.

---

*Toy data:*

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- transform(expand.grid(cus_key=paste0(LETTERS[1:3], sample(12:43, 3)),
                             date=seq.Date(as.Date("2018-05-13"), length.out=5, by="week")),
                 sales=sample(20:80, 15, replace=TRUE))
```